# How to moving top div to the bottom of a stack

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-animate

```
<div>                       <div>
 <div>1</div>  ------------  <div>2</div> 
 <div>2</div>  -transition-  <div>3</div>
 <div>3</div>  ------------  <div>1</div>
</div>                      </div>
```

Is their a way in jquery to remove the the first child of a div and appending it to the last child in one chain? Example div 1 fades out is then appended to the div 3 and fades in
I can only get the first child removed from the top or appended to the last child, but I cannot do it in one load. I also tried putting the divs in an array to make the easier to manipulate, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You said you managed to remove and append it already - can you show us what you tried and what isn't working with it?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div > div').first().fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).appendTo($(this).parent()).fadeIn();
})​;
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/npCEz/1)

Should be noted that those "I need to do it with one line code" requirements are silly.

Answer (score 1):

gdoron doesnt work, slight tweak.

```
$('div > div').first().fadeOut('slow', function() {
  $(this).appendTo($(this).parent()).fadeIn(); 
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:
http://jsfiddle.net/V5bkC/

I'd usually animate the height of the item after it fades out, but I'll leave that part to you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you append an element that is already in the DOM it is automatically removed from its current position, so simply do that in the complete callback of .fadeOut().

```
var $first = $("div div").first();
$first.fadeOut(500, function() {
   $first.appendTo($first.parent()).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tfEMq/

If you put the above in a function you can have it run continuously by adding a callback to the .fadeIn(): http://jsfiddle.net/tfEMq/1/